# Spliting keras model into multiple GPU's

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, gpu

Dear fellow Data Scientists.
I'm having a problem with splitting model into multiple GPU's. I have read something about "towering" in native tensorflow but my whole architecture is already written in keras (tensorflow backend of course). Keras as far as I know only supports data paralellism which is useless while operating on images bigger than 1760x1760 in my case(Yolo architecture). I'm asking for advice, how could I achieve this without using native tensorflow I must run this model on 4500x4500 images and I can use up to 4 Tesla k40 (11GB) GPU's.

EDIT:
I'm already using batch = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the device parallelism (aka model parallelism) see this FAQ: [Device parallelism](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#device-parallelism).

[Here](https://gist.github.com/alsrgv/cbbb2e25f09c1df983098098511d16c4) is an example of doing this with Horovod.

Answer (score 1):

## One graph - multiple GPUs

In order to specify specific GPU for layers, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51251166/how-do-you-specify-that-a-specific-keras-layer-should-be-assigned-to-the-cpu) can be helpful. Just specify for layer the GPU device.

## Multiple copies of graph - multi_gpu_model()

There is a [multi_gpu_model()](https://keras.io/utils/#multi_gpu_model) function in Keras which will make your training be distributed on multiple GPUs on one machine.

But, as it is stated in the documentation, this approach copies the graph on multiple GPUs and splits the batches to those multiple GPUs and later fuses them.

When using this `multi_gpu_model()` be aware that you might encounter [a problem with saving](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8123) such model, but it can be easily solved by saving the original model as stated is [this answer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8123#issuecomment-348976624).

Comment: I have had mentioned that Keras supports only model paralellism, not model distribution across multiple GPU's. It's great for faster training but I need to merge those 4 GPU's so they could fit the computation graph without having problems with allocation.

Comment: Oh, I see now. I didn't then understand your question, sorry.

Comment: I will edit the answer.